# Key Click Delay

Tags: python

I am very new to python and am attempting to write a basic game with tkinter that lets me pick numbers 1-4 by hitting number keys, and it will then take the random number variable related to that key, and then display the random number on the screen. I have the display part and key press part down, however I want to know how I am supposed to force the player to wait before they can display more text.

This question also isnt related to the question, but it is related to the game. How do I destroy the text that I put on the canvas so that I can put a different bit in its place.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xS3OT.png)

```
import random
import time
tk = Tk()

number1 = (random.randint(0, 3))
number2 = (random.randint(0,3))
number3 = (random.randint(0,3))
number4 = (random.randint(0,3))

canvas = Canvas(tk, width=500, height=500)
canvas.pack()
canvas.create_text(250, 150, text="Press the keys 1, 2, or 3",font=('Arial', 20))

def doGame(event):
 if event.keysym == '1':
  canvas.create_text(250, 250, text=number1,font=('Arial',20))
 elif event.keysym == '2':    
  canvas.create_text(250, 250, text=number2,font=('Arial',20))
 elif event.keysym == '3':
  canvas.create_text(250, 250, text=number3,font=('Arial',20))
 elif event.keysym == '4':
  canvas.create_text(250, 250, text=number4,font=('Arial',20))
for i in range(0, 100000):
 canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-1>', doGame)
 canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-2>', doGame)
 canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-3>', doGame)
 canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-4>', doGame)
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible example of what you've tried and the behavior you would like?

Comment: If you want to see the code look at the image.

Comment: As for what I tried, I tried using time.sleep in the for loop but that just breaks the code

Comment: Nope, that's not how it works.  You need to post your code as text so we can cut-and-paste it.

Comment: By the way, "bind_all" just records the callback to use.  You only need to call it once per event.  I'm not sure what you were trying to do with that loop.

Comment: I spent 5 minutes trying to format the code on here right but I cant annoyingly, so I think im going to delete the post

Comment: Put three backticks "```" before the code and three backticks after.

Comment: I tried using the loop to make it so that there was a delay in between when i pressed, but that broke so I can just delete the for

Comment: I did the backticks but it requires me to some indentations that arent in my original code and I cant figure that out

Comment: No indentation adjustments needed - just the backticks on a line before and after. Although I have to say that using 1-space indentation is hard to read - 4-space is normal.

Comment: Alright I edited the post and the code is now on it

Answer (score 1):

You need to run `tk.mainloop()` to properly hand over control to the GUI.

To get the delay you want after some `doGame` action, you need another "clean-up" function that you call a little while later specified by the `canvas.after` function. This can also be used to reset up the action message, so it falls naturally to the same function to initialize, and this can bind key presses to the `doGame` function.

To delete text from the screen, you'll need to hang on to the id of widget as your create it, then use `.delete`. This is done below by keeping IDs in the `prompt` list.

Unbinding  events during the message pause reduces screen confusion, but needs a re-bind during clean-up. If you comment out the `.unbind` line you will potentially overlay a lot of messages on top of each other (& this is why I had `prompt` as a list).

Sample implementation:

```
canvas = Canvas(tk, width=500, height=500)
canvas.pack()

number1 = (random.randint(1,8))
number2 = (random.randint(1,8))*10
number3 = (random.randint(1,8))*100
number4 = (random.randint(1,8))*1000

prompt = []
gameDisplay = {'1':number1, '2':number2, '3':number3, '4':number4 } # info for various keys

def startScreen():
    while len(prompt) > 0:
        canvas.delete(prompt.pop()) # release ID, clear text 
    prompt.append(canvas.create_text(250, 150, text="Press the keys 1, 2, or 3",font=('Arial', 20)))
    tk.bind("<Key>", doGame)

def doGame(event):
    ch = event.char
    canvas.delete(prompt[0])
    dText = 'pressed '+ch
    if ch in gameDisplay:
        dText += ' value '+str(gameDisplay[ch])
    prompt.append(canvas.create_text(250, 250, text=dText, font=('Arial',20)))
    tk.unbind("<Key>") # ignore keys until...
    canvas.after(1000,startScreen) # wait 1000ms then run this fuction

startScreen()
tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: The problem with this is that I am trying to make it so that it does something when you hit a key. If I try putting it in a loop (which it is also requiring me to do for some reason in order to run the key press code) and then adding the wait, it ends up never running my code. I need this so that I can display text without allowing you to make a blob of text on the screen

Answer (score 0):

To create a time delay before executing the next line of code you can use time module sleep function:

```
import time


time.sleep(3.0)
# program will wait 3 seconds then prints:
print("3 seconds")
```

Comment: The problem with this is that I am trying to make it so that it does something when you hit a key. If I try putting it in a loop (which it is also requiring me to do for some reason in order to run the key press code) and then adding the wait, it ends up never running my code. I need this so that I can display text without allowing you to make a blob of text on the screen.